# Switch from "Tabbed Application" template to "Page Based Application"

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode-template

I've been building my app with the "Tabbed Application" template, but I have decided that I no longer want to use tabs to switch my views and that I would rather use the "Page Based Application" style with the tiny dots on the bottom of the screen as my app is only 2 pages/view controllers.

When I start a new Page Based Application I notice that Xcode includes a "Model Controller" document. This appears to look much different from the way the Tabbed Application is set up and I'm not sure how to either move all of my code over to the Page Based template or "convert" my Tabbed Application to a Page Based one.